# Create Tigase admin user after switch to mongodb

Tags: xmpp, chat, tigase

I have successfully installed Tigase with mysql and everything worked great.

After I switched to mongodb, I have a new database created in mongodb with default schema, but missing the admin user.

My question is how do I create the admin user in the mongodb?

Are there any scripts that can be run from the terminal, that can create admin user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no classic roles in Tigase.

If you want a user to be admin, just set it in the /[tigase_server_location]/etc/init.properties

--admins = username@domain

Now username@domain will be able to e.g. use the Tigase Web UI.